# fields and subspaces

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis, vector-spaces, finite-fields

Let F be a field and let V=F^F, which is a vector space over F. Let w be the set of all functions f element of V satisfying f(1)=f(-1). Is W a subspace of V?

a. Has the zero vector 
b. closed under vector addition.
c. closed under scalar multiplication.

can someone show me how to prove this?

Comment: I thought in the definition of a field a multiplicative inverse has to exist for everything except the zero vector, because otherwise you wouldn't have an additive identity element.

Comment: @Silynn, yes, i double checked, I do believe you are correct. I edited my comment

Answer (score 1):

Let the map

$$\Phi\colon V\rightarrow \Bbb F, \quad f\mapsto f(1)-f(-1)$$
the we see easily that $\Phi$  is a linear form:
$$\Phi(\lambda f+g)=\lambda \Phi(f)+\Phi(g)$$
so $W=\ker \Phi$ is an hyperplane (subspace) of $V$.